# Wrapping my head around N parent->child associations

Tags: c#, recursion, parent, relationship

I'll try to explain this the best I can. I'm having quite a bit of difficulty trying to figure out this logic.

Basically, I have a collection that includes thousands of objects which are each made up of a Parent and a Child property.

So, roughly, this:

```
public class MyObject{
     public string Parent { get; set; }
     public string Child { get; set; }
}
```

What I'm trying to figure out is how to build this out into a plain TreeView control. I need to build the relationships but I can't figure out how to because they can be mixed. I can probably explain this better with what the tree should look like:

So if I have the following items inside of my collection:

```
0. Parent: "A", Child: "B"
1. Parent: "B", Child: "C"
2. Parent: "B", Child: "D"
```

I would want my tree to look this like:

```
-A
--B
---C
-A
--B
---D
-B
--C
-B
--D
```

How can I do this in C#? I would need it to support up to N relationships as we have some branches I would expect to reach about 50 nodes deep.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE**

This problem actually turned out to be considerably more complex than I originally realized, given the requirement of repeating the *entire tree* for each path.  I've simply deleted the old code as I don't want to add any further confusion.

I do want to keep it on record that using a recursive data structure makes this easier:

```
public class MyRecursiveObject
{
    public MyRecursiveObject Parent { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<MyRecursiveObject> Children { get; set; }
}
```

You'll see very clearly **why** this is easier after reading the implementation code below:

```
private void PopulateTree(IEnumerable<MyObject> items)
{
    var groupedItems =
        from i in items
        group i by i.Parent into g
        select new { Name = g.Key, Children = g.Select(c => c.Child) };
    var lookup = groupedItems.ToDictionary(i => i.Name, i => i.Children);
    foreach (string parent in lookup.Keys)
    {
        if (lookup.ContainsKey(parent))
            AddToTree(lookup, Enumerable.Empty<string>(), parent);
    }
}

private void AddToTree(Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> lookup,
    IEnumerable<string> path, string name)
{
    IEnumerable<string> children;
    if (lookup.TryGetValue(name, out children))
    {
        IEnumerable<string> newPath = path.Concat(new string[] { name });
        foreach (string child in children)
            AddToTree(lookup, newPath, child);
    }
    else
    {
        TreeNode parentNode = null;
        foreach (string item in path)
            parentNode = AddTreeNode(parentNode, item);
        AddTreeNode(parentNode, name);
    }
}

private TreeNode AddTreeNode(TreeNode parent, string name)
{
    TreeNode node = new TreeNode(name);
    if (parent != null)
        parent.Nodes.Add(node);
    else
        treeView1.Nodes.Add(node);
    return node;
}
```

First of all, I realized that the dictionary will contain keys for intermediate nodes as well as just the root nodes, so we don't need two recursive calls in the recursive `AddToTree` method in order to get the "B" nodes as roots; the initial walk in the `PopulateTree` method already does it.

What we **do** need to guard against is adding leaf nodes in the initial walk; using the data structure in question, these are detectable by checking whether or not there is a key in the parent dictionary.  With a recursive data structure, this would be way easier: Just check for `Parent == null`.  But, a recursive structure is not what we have, so the code above is what we have to use.

The `AddTreeNode` is mostly a utility method, so we don't have to keep repeating this null-checking logic later.

The real ugliness is in the second, recursive `AddToTree` method.  Because we are trying to create a unique copy of every single subtree, we can't simply add a tree node and then recurse with that node as the parent.  "A" only has one child here, "B", but "B" has two children, "C" and "D".  There needs to be two copies of "A", but there's no way to know about that when "A" is originally passed to the `AddToTree` method.

So what we actually have to do is not create *any* nodes until the final stage, and store a temporary path, for which I've chosen `IEnumerable<string>` because it's immutable and therefore impossible to mess up.  When there are more children to add, this method simply adds to the path and recurses; when there are no more children, it walks the entire saved path and adds a node for each.

This is *extremely* inefficient because we are now creating a new enumerable on every invocation of `AddToTree`.  For large numbers of nodes, it is likely to chew up a lot of memory.  This works, but it would be a lot more efficient with a recursive data structure.  Using the example structure at the top, you wouldn't have to save the path at all or create the dictionary; when no children are left, simply walk up the path in a `while` loop using the `Parent` reference.

Anyway, I guess that's academic because this isn't a recursive object, but I thought it was worth pointing out anyway as something to keep in mind for future designs.  The code above *will* produce exactly the results you want, I've gone ahead and tested it on a real TreeView.

---

**UPDATE 2** - So it turns out that the version above is pretty brutal with respect to memory/stack, most likely a result of creating all those `IEnumerable<string>` instances.  Although it's not great design, we can remove that particular issue by changing to a mutable `List<string>`.  The following snippet shows the differences:

```
private void PopulateTree(IEnumerable<MyObject> items)
{
    // Snip lookup-generation code - same as before ...

    List<string> path = new List<string>();
    foreach (string parent in lookup.Keys)
    {
        if (lookup.ContainsKey(parent))
            AddToTree(lookup, path, parent);
    }
}

private void AddToTree(Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> lookup,
    IEnumerable<string> path, string name)
{
    IEnumerable<string> children;
    if (lookup.TryGetValue(name, out children))
    {
        path.Add(name);
        foreach (string child in children)
            AddToTree(lookup, newPath, child);
        path.Remove(name);
    }
    // Snip "else" block - again, this part is the same as before ...
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you. I haven't really used LINQ much but I'm taking a look at your second example to see if I can make that work. Unfortunately I can't really change the structure but this is a type of thing that won't be run much (I'd love to use your first bit but I'd have to build out the relationships from this bad data, somehow, which was my issue).

Comment: @Kris: Good thing I added the second bit then.  Hopefully it's not buggy, I already had to fix it twice. :P

Comment: Ack... I just realized it *was* bugged, this version should work now!  I'm going to bed...

Comment: Thank you, I think you got me close. I'm getting a Stack Overflow exception as I think this ends up producing an infinite recursion loop but I'll try to figure it out.

Comment: @Kris: This is why one shouldn't write code after a 12-hour work day and near-total exhaustion.  The previous answer was just wrong, I've rewritten it to be correct.  Also note that if you're populating a `TreeView` you should always call the `BeginUpdate` and `EndUpdate` methods before making any major changes; I didn't put that in the above code because I didn't want to clutter it up with anything unrelated to the algorithm itself.

Comment: Thank you. This produces the exact results I'm looking for. Unfortunately it only works if I have, roughly, 60-70 MyObjects in my collection. As it stands now, I have over 700. If I let this run on 100 MyObjects it'll run forever, using up over 3GB of ram before eventually crashing.

If I attempt to do it on 400 or even 700 items it'll eventually throw a stack overflow exception.

Do you think what I need to do is just not possible? I'm going to look over your stuff to try and figure out some ways of saving memory.

Comment: @Kris: It's probably all of the successive `IEnumerable<string>` instances that are causing that.  I guess it's not as efficient as I would have expected.  The easiest way to resolve that is to use a mutable list instead, and I'll put in an update to show that.  Note that this isn't very good design; my "production-quality" solution would probably be to have a mapper that transforms your string-map into the recursive data structures, then a separate function that populates the tree using your special rules.

Comment: Thanks but that didn't change much. The memory usage is a little better but it'll eventually hit a stack overflow exception. Not entirely sure why yet.

Thanks for all the help, though. You've been a huge help. I have trouble wrapping my head around this type of logic.

Comment: @Kris: If you're still getting a stack overflow in that code, then either you have a cycle in your tree, or you have an insane nesting depth.  I'm actually betting on the former.  Perhaps you should post the data on pastebin.

Comment: Thanks, I added code to remove any circular issues with parents and children (there were only 6) and I am making sure the list is distinct. Still have the same issue but I'll debug further. I, unfortunately, cannot post the data. Thanks for all of your help.

Answer (score 0):

like rubens, I tried both, but a little better I think [A Generic Tree Collection](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/treecollection2.aspx)

this tree collection got some nice functionality build-in to move around the tree, go read the whole article

sample with the link above

```
Static Class Module1
{

    public static void Main()
    {
        Common.ITree<myObj> myTree = default(Common.ITree<myObj>);
        myObj a = new myObj("a");
        myObj b = new myObj("b");
        myObj c = new myObj("c");
        myObj d = new myObj("d");

        myTree = Common.NodeTree<myObj>.NewTree;
        myTree.InsertChild(a).InsertChild(b).InsertChild(c).Parent.Parent.InsertNext(a).InsertChild(b).InsertChild(d).Parent.Parent.InsertNext(b).InsertChild(c).Parent.InsertNext(b).InsertChild(d);

        Console.WriteLine(myTree.ToStringRecursive);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

Class myObj
{
    public string text;

    public myObj(string value)
    {
        text = value;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return text;
    }
}
```

would be exactly what you just showed

> -A
>   --B
>   ---C
>   -A
>   --B
>   ---D
>   -B
>   --C
>   -B
>   --D

Comment: All this seems to accomplish is switching the `TreeView` for an `ITree<T>`.  The actual tree construction is completely hard-coded, and that doesn't really answer the question...

Comment: Yeah, thanks but actually creating the tree wasn't an issue; getting the data together was.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, what you're trying to do is take one tree and transform it into another.  The transformation essentially takes each non-leaf-node in the input tree and creates a node for it (and its descendants) in the output tree.

First off, you'll be happier if you design a data structure for your nodes that is genuinely recursive:

```
public class Node
{
   public Node Parent { get; private set; }
   public IEnumerable<Node> Children { get; private set; }
   public bool HasChildren { get { return Children.Count() > 0; } }

   public Node()
   {
      Children = new List<Node>();
   }
}
```

Your `MyObject` class represents parent/child relationships between string values.  As long as you're able to implement a `FindChildren()` method that returns the child values for a given parent value, using this class to rationalize the parent/child relationships is straightforward:

```
public string Value { get; set; }
public static Node Create(string parentKey)
{
   Node n = new Node();
   n.Value = parentKey;
   foreach (string childKey in FindChildren(parentKey))
   {
      Node child = n.Children.Add(Node.Create(childKey));
      child.Parent = n;
   } 
   return n;
}
```

It's simple to implement a property that returns a node's descendants:

```
public IEnumerable<Node> Descendants
{
   get
   {
      foreach (Node child in Children)
      {
         yield return child;
         foreach (Node descendant in child.Descendants)
         {
            yield return descendant;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

To add a `Node` to a TreeView, you need two methods.  (Note that these aren't methods of the `Node` class!)  I've made them overloads, but an argument can be made for giving them different names:

```
public void AddNode(Node n, TreeView tv)
{
   TreeNode tn = tv.Nodes.Add(n.Value);
   tn.Tag = n;
   foreach (Node child in n.Children)
   {
      AddNode(child, tn);
   }
}

public void AddNode(Node n, TreeNode parent)
{
   TreeNode tn = parent.Nodes.Add(n.Value);
   parent.Tag = n;
   foreach (Node child in n.Children)
   {
      AddNode(child, tn);
   }
}
```

I'm setting the `Tag` on each `TreeNode` so that you can find your way back to the original `Node`.

So to initialize your `TreeView` from a list of top-level parent keys, you need a method like this:

```
public void PopulateTreeView(IEnumerable<string> parents, TreeView t)
{
   foreach (string parentKey in parents)
   {
      Node n = Node.Create(parentKey);
      AddNode(n, t);
      foreach (Node descendant in n.Descendants)
      {
         if (n.HasChildren)
         {
            AddNode(descendant, t);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**Edit:**

I didn't quite understand how your `MyObject` class was working; I think I do now, and I've edited this accordingly.

Comment: Each parent may have multiple childs so FindChild() isn't a straight forward operation. I'm not sure how to adapt your solution to my data structure.

If I created a FindChild() method I would have to return multiple children which wouldn't allow me to create the Tree structure I need.

Thanks, though.

Comment: I see; I misunderstood what your class is actually doing:  each instance represents a single association between a parent value and a child value.  I've edited my answer to account for that.  You still need a `FindChildren` method, but if you don't already have a way of finding all the children of a given parent you've got bigger problems than this one.

Comment: FindChildren is fine; creating a FindChild method wouldn't quite work and that was what I was referring to.

Thanks for the solution; I'm trying to take a look at it now but get a stack overflow exception really quickly. I'll debug further.